# How do you resize a screen (or "canvas") in Expression Blend +Sketchflow?

Tags: expression-blend, sketchflow, mockups

You can't select the actual "Screen" by clicking on it in the designer.  Even if you have no other elements added.  If you add any element, you get the typical resize behavior you would expect, but since you cannot select the screen, you cannot resize it or even view the properties.

Comment: What is the question here?  I see you posted an answer as well?

Comment: The question is, "How do you resize a screen in Expression Blend + Sketchflow" which should be implied by the subject and the tags (Normally when I put the product name in the question someone comes along and removes it and says it's redundant with the tags).  As for posting an answer, yes, I did.  There is an option when you are posting a question to "Also post an answer".  Since I discovered the answer before posting and could not find a similar question I thought it would be beneficial for future users who have the same problem.  Thanks for the downvote though...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, simply asked a question.

Comment: I see, apologies for assuming.  It's back to zero now either way.  Hopefully this will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to select the screen in the "Objects and Timeline" list.  Once you do, you get the expected resize handles and can even view the properties using the tab on the right and resize it manually there.

Comment: If this is the answer, go ahead and accept it even though it is your own.

Comment: Once resized with the handles I find it useful to right-click on the screen (canavs) surface and from the Layout sub-menu click "Fill [whichever axis you have just changed]" (I think this is only applicable if you have increased a size)